# Swift convert string date to date

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I have this string "Apr 13, 2020 7:53:01 PM" and I want convert to Date. I used this but it crashes

```
 let input = "Apr 13, 2020 7:53:01 PM"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from:input)!
```

How is the correct dateFormat for convert this string? Thanks

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-YYYY'T'HH:mm:ss a"` What do you think you wrote on that line? What's the purpose of `dateFormat`? Once you understand that, it might be clearer what's wrong with your code. Also, understanding that it's crashing because `dateFormatter.date(from:input)` is nil, and force unwrapping it (using `!` on it) is causing the crash is understood by you, I hope. As well as the error thrown in console.

Comment: I want convert the string in a Date object, because I have a lot of object that I want order by date. I say that it crashes because it is nil, but it is nil because the dateFormat is incorrect

Comment: So you seem to understand that you date format is wrong? Did you try to understand what you wrote on it? It doesn't match the format of the input. Simply write one above the other, you'll see.

Comment: I say it but I try a lot of format date. I see in NSDateFormatter.com but it doesn't work... I try also "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" but nothing

Comment: You didn't said previsouly that you did some attempts. The last dateformat you gave makes more sense. `HH`? That's for 24h format. In case of a doubt, do the reverse: `let stringified = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())` and see if it seems correct. Also `Apr`, is that English only and not It? The locale here could causes an issue.

Comment: Yes I do a lot of attempts, the problem is the locale. I removed it and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes date format to this

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

Comment: still crashing? It's work on my side with that pre input date.